# Given that $z$ is a complex number, find the least integer greater than $z^{2000} + (\frac{1}{z})^{2000}$ if $z + \frac1z = 2\cos3$.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, complex-numbers, integers

**Problem**: Given that $z$ is a complex number, find the least integer greater than $z^{2000} + (\frac{1}{z})^{2000}$ if $z + \frac1z = 2\cos3$.

I found $z$ but then just found the answer to be infinity. Can someone help?

Comment: Are you trying to find $z^{2000}+\frac1{z^{2000}}$ ? What is $(z +\frac1z)^2$ ?

Comment: z^2000 + 1/z^2000

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: You *must* clear up what you mean.  Use parenthesis if you don't want to learn MathJax to type fractions.

Comment: Interesting fact.  If $z = a+bi = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}(a' + b'i)$ then $\frac 1z = \frac 1{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}(a' -b'i)$.  So if $|z| = \sqrt{a^2 +b^2} = 1$ then if $z = a+bi$ then $\frac 1z = a-bi$ and $z + \frac 1z = 2a$.  That's the case here:  $z = \cos 3 \pm i\sin 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z + \frac 1z = 2\cos 3$  multiply both sides by $z$

$z^2 + 1 = 2\cos 3z$

$z^2 - 2\cos 3z + 1=0$

$x = \frac {2\cos 3 \pm \sqrt{4\cos^2 3 - 4}}2=\cos 3\pm \sqrt{\cos^2 3-1}$

$\cos 3\pm i\sqrt{1-\cos^2 3}=$

$\cos 3\pm i\sin 3=$

$e^{\pm 3i}$

So $\frac 1z = e^{\mp 3i}$

And $z + (\frac 1z)^{2000}=$

$e^{\pm 3i} + e^{\mp 6000i} =$

$\cos 3 \pm i\sin 3 + \cos 6000 \mp i\sin 6000=$

$(\cos 3+\cos 6000) \pm (\sin 3 - \sin 6000) i$.